# Нарисовать полукруг / сектор круга на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли с помощью API создать полуокружность на карте или сектор (не в виде треугольника, а чтобы на конце была дуга), посоветуйте как это сделать.

В качестве известных данных. Радиус, Направление, угол ф, начальная точка. Знаю что есть прямая и обратная геодезическая задача, но у меня нет конечной точки, только расстояние и направление. По большому счёту интересует вопрос отрисовки секторов на карте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто нарисовать полигон нужной формы.

Самое простое решение выглядит так: http://jsfiddle.net/tLs0d51u/
Но там получился не совсем круг, поскольку круг формируется в сферических координатах (в широте и долготе), а не в декартовых.

Чтобы нарисовать нормальный круг, нужно работать с глобальными пиксельными координатами, а затем перевести их в сферические.
Это можно сделать так:

```
var zoom = map.getZoom();
var projection = map.options.get('projection');

// широта и долгота -> пиксели
projection.toGlobalPixels([55.73, 37.75], zoom);

// пиксели -> широта и долгота
projection.fromGlobalPixels([158560.7111111111, 82211.42703728657], zoom);
```

Сектор нормального круга: http://jsfiddle.net/tLs0d51u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Отрисовывал сектор через решение прямой геодезической задачи, при этом в исходных данных имел радиус, угол, координаты начальной точки.

```
 function getAreaCoord(point, azimut, corner, length) {// получение координат сектора
var sector = [];
var firstSide = Math.PI * ((360 - azimut) + 90) / 180, // азимут в радианах
secondSide = firstSide - (Math.PI * corner / 180),
dir2 = [Math.sin(firstSide), Math.cos(firstSide)]; // направление по азимуту
sector[0] = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.solveDirectProblem(point, dir2, length).endPoint;
var i = 1;
for(var sectopPoint = 5; sectopPoint <= corner; sectopPoint += 5) {
var middlePoint = sectopPoint;
var side = firstSide - (Math.PI * middlePoint / 180);
var dir4 = [Math.sin(side), Math.cos(side)];
sector[i] = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.solveDirectProblem(point, dir4, length).endPoint;
i++
}
return sector;
}
```