# Yandex Maps JA API 2.1 (2.1.79) – Круг отображается эллипсом (не связно с эффектом проекции на плоскость)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карта-api

Перешел с Yandex Maps JS API V3 на V2.1.79.

Использовал простой код для отрисовки геодезически-верного круга (то есть того, который на реальной местности круг, а на плоской карте может иметь искажения, например стать эллипсом)

```
var turfCircle = turf.circle(userHomeCoordinates, userRadius, {steps: 64, units: 'kilometers'});
```

В V3 всё работало корректно, но при переходе в V2.1.79 круг вдруг стал эллипсом. причем эффект не пропадает на малом масштабе (когда эффект кривизны поверхности совсем не заметен – и этот геодезически круг должен почти идеально совпадать с кругом на экране).

Понимаю, про что изменился порядок координат между двумя версиями API, это у меня учтено.

Столкнулся ровно с той же нерешенной проблемой в этих примерах:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777667/578311

https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1793

причём искажение "ровно такое же", то есть в примерах визуально эллипсы "настолько же" отличаются от круга, как и у меня на карте. То есть я думаю, что это какой-то общий эффект, причем исходя из того что онид из ответов был защитан как правильный в 2018 году, думаю, что что-то изменилось в API яндекс карт.

Вот пара скриншотов таких "эллипсов на полях"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-либо знает причину и метод устранения искажения - буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Вы, кажется, самостоятельно нашли метод устранения — верный ответ от 18 года. 
Чудо, что в новой версии API всё работает так, как вы хотите. Но в 2.1 Яндекс всё равно изменения для безупречной работы со сторонними модулями изменения вносить не будет.